# Angular Как добавить класс внутрь класса компонента?

Tags: typescript, angular

У меня есть класс компонента, я хочу внутрь него добавить еще один класс для рассчетов, но внутрь класса добавить не получается, только снаружи. Что нужно сделать, чтобы добавить?

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() {
}
public class Abc {

    }
  }
```

Comment: [can-you-create-nested-classes-in-typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494174/can-you-create-nested-classes-in-typescript)
 и 
[typescript-using-the-type-of-a-static-inner-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864291/typescript-using-the-type-of-a-static-inner-class/42865425)

Answer (score 1):

## Как добавить класс внутрь класса?

использовать `namespace`

- http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes
- http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts

```
class Proger {
    props: Proger.defaulProps;
    constructor(
        props: Proger.defaulProps | Proger.$props
    ) {
        if (props instanceof Proger.defaulProps) {
            this.props = props
        } else {
            this.props = new Proger.defaulProps(props)
        }
    }
}
namespace Proger {
    export type $props = Partial<defaulProps>
        & Required<Pick<defaulProps, 'language'>>;
    export class defaulProps {
        married: boolean = false;
        sex: 'male' | 'female' | 'regular' | null = 'regular';
        bearded: boolean = true;
        language: string = '';
        constructor(props: $props) {
            Object.assign(this, props)
        }
    }
}
```

```
t1: {
    const p = new Proger(new Proger.defaulProps({ language: 'Pascal' }))
    console.log(p.props)
}
t2: {
    const p = new Proger({ language: 'Pascal' })
    console.log(p.props)
}
```